# SharePoint 2013 - How to search a list using a property from the current list

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part

Is it at all possible to search (using a content search web part) a SharePoint 2013 list via a variable in the displayform's currently loaded list item?

In my list I have an audience variable and I'd like to be able to search the entire list via this variable but only when it is related to the current list item. The variable is searchable, and works if I hardcode a term (`"audience = central"` or `"audience = north"` for example) but for the life of me I cannot work out how to write my query so it takes the current list item's variable.

The logic, as I understand it would be

> display all list items where audience = current list item's audience

What I currently have is

```
path:"SHAREPOINT ADDRESS"  (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") NewsAudienceOWSMTXT:{Listitem.NewsAudienceOWSMTXT}"
```

Any help would be most appreciated.